# Can a CD40110 start counting from 1?

Tags: clock, driver, counter, binary

I have a small assignment to made a century clock (which includes year, month, day, hour, minute, and second) without using a microcontroller.

I decided to use a CD40110 to drive a common-cathode 7-segment LED directly instead of using two separate ICs (a counter such as the 74LS90 and a driver such as the 74247). I have some problems when dealing with year-month-day. I attach my circuit schematic for month only below:

[image: My schematic in proteus]

How can I start counting from 1 instead of 0 with a CD40110? I've tried to connect my logic reset to clock-up so when it resets, it will have a pulse to clock to display 1 directly but it didn't work.

If the CD40110 can't do it, could you recommend a more feasible solution?

Comment: Simplest thing is to go with separate counters and decoder/drivers. You need a counter with a parallel load capability, like a 74HC163.

Comment: @DaveTweed thank you for your recommendation, I tried to use just 1 IC for each digit. But it seems not feasible, so may be I will try seperate counter and driver